# How to match index customize page to less style page for a website

Tags: css, indexing, less

I have created a website and it uses less with css for style page, on the other hand, i have created a customization page with some inputs. So i wanna match the value of my less variables with the arrivals of my inputs. how can i do it?

Comment: I would imagine you could do it with a "less" variable, but your question is too vague to really answer the question.

Comment: I know i can do it with less, but i don't know how to match the value of my variables with the arrivals f my input. For example: i have a input that is for background,I set it to #0099cc, and in that style page, i have a variable with less that is for background-color, so how can i match them together?!?

Comment: It depends on the context. Are these variables created randomly throughout your website? Are they within specific tags? There needs to be a constant for it to work. If you are echoing them you should been able to add some identifier there.

Comment: Thanks, i got how to add a identifier, but i still have a problem, how can i match the identifier with my input value?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what it sounds like you are trying to do, it seems like this could work. Although I don't know what languages you are using.

```
echo '<span id="identifier">Your generated values</span>';
```

Then in your CSS..

```
#identifier{ background-color: #0099cc; }
```